# WS-I Compliance Tool Does not Support Soap Protocol 1.2 in the WSDL

Tags: wsdl, soapui, ws-i

I am trying to validate our WSDL's to be compliant with WS-I's [Interoperability Testing Tools 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=testingtools) tool that comes with SoapUI (pro or otherwise, 4.6 - 5.1), but the bundled tool is from 2005 when protocol Soap 1.2 had not been around.

This causes several assertions to fail in the generate report, namely BP2032 and BP2402, and several others prerequisite failures (BP2012, BP2017, BP2117, etc...). Upon investigating some of these assertion failures, it seems like they are not valid at all as the WSDL is indeed in compliance with the description of each item. We have no Soap 1.2 specific feature in the WSDL's (only use the namespace based on requirements). If I revert back to Soap 1.1, the WS-I Compliance (of SoapUI) passes all the assertions.

The WS-I.org website offers a newer addition for the tool's profile, but it seems like it is simply an XSLT with no instruction as to how they need to be run (no Java run time jar) -- [BSP 1.1 Test Tools](http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=testingtools). My question is, how can I validate WSDL's with WS-I compliance (in SoapUI) when Soap 1.2 is used?